# How can we do Fasting on Shiva Rathri After Ekadasi Fasting?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

We require to do parana(consume food) on dwadasi i.e. next day after ekadasi fasting, I want to know how people fast for maha shivaratri if it is falling on dwadasi? As it requires us to do parana for sure to break the ekadasi fasting.

Comment: You can not do the ekadasi fast if you want to do the mahasivaratri one and vice versa.Since Mahasivaratri comes only once in year whereas there are 24 ekadasis in a year you can opt to miss one.:)BTw, Vijaya ekadasi is on coming saturday and parana is on sunday while mahasivaratri is on monday in my place.

Comment: Fasting on both Ekadasis and Pradosham days are impossible since they fall on consecutive days.But Masik Shivaratri(& Maha Shivaratri) and Ekadasi are always separated by atleast one day.So no problems in observing both these two fasts.You should check the panchanga once again.I think you're mistaken.

Comment: Sivaratri never falls on dwadasi. It always falls on bahula chaturdasi.